# Group a Map list by field in java?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a Map list like this:

```java
        Map<String, Object[]> dates = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>();
        dates.put("1", new Object[] {"Group ID", "Group Name", "Product", "Mode" });
        dates.put("2", new Object[] {1, "foo", "PHONE", 11});
        dates.put("3", new Object[] {1, "foo", "Ipad", 12});
        dates.put("4", new Object[] {1, "foo", "Air Pod", 13});
        dates.put("6", new Object[] {2, "boo", "Lumia", 14});
        dates.put("7", new Object[] {2, "boo", "Oppo", 13});
        dates.put("8", new Object[] {2, "boo", "Xiaomi", 15});
        dates.put("9", new Object[] {3, "loo", "Tesla", 10});
        dates.put("10", new Object[] {3, "loo", "Audi", 15});
        dates.put("11", new Object[] {3, "loo", "Ford", 19});
```

How can I group the Map list by Group Id and Group Name
After handling it should look like:

```
1 - foo
Product | Mode
Phone   | 11
Ipad    | 12
Air Pod | 13

2 - boo
Product | Mode
Lumia   | 14
Oppo    | 13
Xiaomi  | 15

3 - loo
Product | Mode
Tesla   | 10
Audi    | 15
Ford    | 19
```

Comment: Is there any particularly contextual reason for handling things as a `Map<String, Object[]>`? I ask as your OO structure of the data could be refactored to make this very easy in Java.

Comment: @Harmelodic no,do you have any suggestion data structure to resolve the problem?

Comment: Please try including the code that you have tried so far. [Asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @kalipts Instead of using `Object[]` I would suggest creating a class and having these four fields (groupId, groupName, product, mode) in that class. In this way, you could replace the Map as `Map<String, YourNewClass>`. This would make it much easier.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68335671/group-a-map-list-by-field-in-java#comment120772614_68335671), you are flexible on how the data is structured.

If you defined 2 new classes/records for `Group` and `Product`, then this becomes much easier. For e.g.:

```java
record Product(int id,
               String name,
               int mode) {
}

record Group(int id,
             String name,
             List<Product> products) {
}
```

You can then create your data as such (I have chosen to ignore the header strings of your given example):

```java
List<Group> groups = List.of(
        new Group(1, "foo", List.of(
                new Product(2, "Ipad", 12),
                new Product(3, "Air Pod", 13),
                new Product(4, "Lumia", 14)
        )),
        new Group(2, "boo", List.of(
                new Product(5, "Oppo", 13),
                new Product(6, "Xiaomi", 15),
                new Product(7, "Tesla", 10)
        )),
        new Group(3, "loo", List.of(
                new Product(8, "Audi", 15),
                new Product(9, "Ford", 19),
                new Product(1, "PHONE", 11)
        ))
);
```

It is then relatively straight forward to just loop through `groups` and then print each of the `group`'s Product's out:

```java
groups.forEach(group -> {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(group.id() + " - " + group.name());
    System.out.println("Product | Mode");
    group.products().stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Product::mode))
            .forEach(product -> System.out.println(product.name() + " | " + product.mode()));
});
```